# Docker container on AWS is constantly restarting

Tags: docker, npgsql

One of the service's container is constantly restarting. From the logs I can see that some request take like 20s, and for some of them there are exceptions like:  An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query. System.InvalidOperationException: An operation is already in progress. at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection or Timeouts. When  I try to access the db with the local  environment, I cannot reproduce such exceptions. On random requests, taking too long, the container restarts. Have somebody had some similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception says, your application is likely trying to use the same physical connection at the same time from multiple threads - but it's impossible to know without seeing some code. Make sure you understand exactly when connections are being used and by which thread, and if you're still stuck try to post a minimal code sample that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I was suspecting the same. I don't have multiple threads in the concrete situation, it turned out that a front-end bug made bulk requests at the same second to the same end-point, query that have include on 4 tables ( I will add the code in my question above). Please note that I'm using the Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=5;MaxPoolSize=80;ConnectionIdleLifetime=30, NpgSql version 3.1.9. .Net Core.I guess I will have the same problem when making a load/performance test. How can I avoid using the same physical connection?

Comment: By the way I cannot post a linq C# code of the query since it is generated with generic functions, but here is the EF generated SQL: SELECT "x"."Id", "x"."Column1", "x"."Column2", "x"."Column3", "x"."Column4", "x"."Column5"
FROM "tabel1" AS "x"
INNER JOIN "table2" AS "c" ON "x"."ColumC" = "c"."Id"
LEFT JOIN "table3" AS "b" ON "x"."ColumnT" = "b"."Id"
LEFT JOIN "table3" AS "f" ON "x"."ColumnM" = "f"."Id"
LEFT JOIN "table4" AS "m" ON "x"."ColumnN" = "m"."Id"
WHERE (("x"."IsActive" = TRUE) AND ("x"."IsParentActive" = TRUE)) 
LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ELB( Elastic Load Balancer ) then increase timeout limit of it .

Comment: Yes, I'm using ELB, but the default timeout of 60s I think is more than enough.